# preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 3

Tags: laravel, preg-match

My laravel Project Route invalid range in character class prolem please help me?

```
Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where( 'path', '([A-z]+)?' )
```

Not solve

```
eRoute::group(['namespace' => 'Post'], function ($router) {
        $router->pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
        // $router->pattern('slug', '.*');
        $router->pattern('slug', '^(?=.*)((?!\/).)*$');

        // SingleStep Post creation
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'CreateOrEdit\SingleStep'], function ($router) {
            Route::get('create', 'CreateController@getForm');
            Route::post('create', 'CreateController@postForm');
            Route::get('create/finish', 'CreateController@finish');
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but do notice that `[A-z]` matches all characters with ascii number between `65` (`A`) and `122`(`z`), which include these characters: ``^`_\[]``

Comment: What routes are you trying to match?

Comment: Route::post('create', 'CreateController@postForm');

Comment: First, check if `'([A-Za-z]+)?'` instead of `'([A-z]+)?'` and `'^[^/]*$'` instead of `'^(?=.*)((?!\/).)*$'` work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the intended routing pattern is supposed to be, but I speculate that it does not supports lookarounds.  So instead of this:

```
$router->pattern('slug', '^(?=.*)((?!\/).)*$')
```

Try this:

```
$router->pattern('slug', '^[^/]*$');
```

Comment: Before it complete ok. but update php version 7.3 now are not work post create route..